# Semiclassical limit $S \to\infty$ in spin model

Tags: hamiltonian, approximations, semiclassical, spin-models

In many literature, the limit $S \to \infty$ is considered as a semiclassical limit. My question is that when this approximation is valid? Since paticles, say electrons, have the fixed spin number $S=1/2$, how does it make sense to talk about $S\to \infty$? 
I will give one example of this approximation being used. The following is part of the book in Altland&Simons:

[image]
[image]

Here the Hamiltonian was approximated for $S>> 1$. In what physical situation does this assumption valid?

Comment: The real answer is: nobody knows. Moreover it depends on the model/situation.

Comment: I'd think it's not spin of a single electron, but rather total spin of the sea of electrons.

Comment: @Ruslan What does it mean by the "total spin of the sea of electron"? If we are considering "composite electron" then it can have higher spin, but I think in this model $S$ represents the spin of the "single" electron.

Comment: Roughly speaking: the higher the spin, the more closely spaced the different projections of the spin vector onto the $z$ axis are. A classical spin should be able to have arbitrary real-valued projection onto a given axis — the direction of the spin vector shouldn't be quantized — and $S \rightarrow \infty$ takes the spacing between projections to zero.